# VueJS listening to keycombinations via mounted event listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have working global key listener, but it manages to catch only single key stroke. How can I catch combinations like ctrl+enter?

```
mounted() 
{
    window.addEventListener
    (
        "keypress", e => 
        {
          console.log(e.key);
        }
    );
},
```

`Input device events`

`click, contextmenu, DOMMouseScroll, dblclick, gamepadconnected, gamepaddisconnected, keydown, keypress, keyup, MozGamepadButtonDown, MozGamepadButtonUp, mousedown, mouseenter, mouseleave, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, mouseup, mousewheel, MozMousePixelScroll, pointerlockchange, pointerlockerror,wheel`

none of those seems to fit it

nor this is not working properly

```
"keypress", e => 
{
    if (e.ctrlKey)
    {
        console.log(e.key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, we're checking ctrl is pressed and the (another) pressed key is not ctrl:

```
window.addEventListener
    (
        "keydown", e => 
        {
          var evt = window.event ? event : e;
          if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode !== 17) {
            console.log('Ctrl + ' + e.key);
          }
        }
    );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gpq5w97/)

You may also be interested in using [vue-global-events](https://github.com/shentao/vue-global-events#readme) which allows you to write global key listeners in Vue style (e.g. `@keyup.ctrl.tab="nextTab"`).